# EFCore 3.1 can not insert Null value to decimal? field and EF changed it to nvarchar

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, type-conversion, nullable

I'm using .net core 3.1. I have a table in MSSQL which has a nullable decimal column, and In code, I define it in its model file as (decimal?). In the repository when I want to insert my model to DB, I have this:

```
//financialDb is my model that I want to add in DB
context.Financial.Add(financialDb);
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

when saveChanges is called, I got this error :

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
 ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__122_0(Task`1 result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__274_0(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
ClientConnectionId:d4ad0287-bbd8-4085-9420-292a8fa161d2
Error Number:8114,State:5,Class:16
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(DbContext _, ValueTuple`2 parameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IReadOnlyList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

when I check the insertion query in the profiler I saw that EFCore change nullable decimal to nvarchar(4000) and because of that, I got this error.
What should I do to fix this problem so I can insert a null value to a nullable decimal column?
I remember in the EF framework I had this problem again but I fixed it by adding "IsOptional" to that property in its config file. But in EF core there is not this option that I can use again.

Comment: You are sure it is defined as a decimal in `Financial` type? Try to add a migration and see, if EF Core can detect, that you are trying to change the datatype for the column to nullable decimal. Otherwise, you could write a migration file yourself, altering the column with `AlterColumn`

Comment: Yes, I checked the type multiple times. The problem is why EF changed the type at the last moment!? And, I wrote this mapping but it didn't work:
`private static decimal? CastFinancialValues(decimal? value)
        {
            var nullableValue = (decimal?)null;
            if (value != null)
            {
                nullableValue = (decimal?) value;
            }
            return nullableValue;
        }`
Instead of this when I cast the property to decimal, the model inserts to the database with zero value against null.

Comment: Now I just changed the type of the property in code from (decimal?) to (long?) and it works! (in database it's still decimal(18,6)) How is it possible? Why doesn't work with decimal?

Comment: Thanks for following up/letting me know. That is really strange, but I am glad you figured it out! Maybe someone more knowledgable than me will see this and chip in.

Comment: @N.Abdolalizadeh you could add your resolution as an answer if you like.